# What happens when you cash out an HSA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

If you cash out a 401k before you're old enough you get a 1099-R. What happens if you cash out an HSA? Do you get a 1099-R or some other sort of 1099?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take any money out of an HSA, you'll get a [1099-SA](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-1099-SA).

HSAs work a little differently than a 401(k).  With a 401(k), you aren't supposed to take any money out until retirement.  HSAs, however, are spending accounts.  I take money out of my HSA every year.

As long as you spend the money you take out of your HSA on qualified medical expenses, there are no taxes or penalties due.  The bank that holds your HSA doesn't know or care what you spend the money on; they will certainly allow you to empty your HSA account.  Anything you take out will be reported to the IRS (and to you) on a 1099-SA.  At tax time, along with your tax return, you send in a [form 8889](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-8889), on which you report to the IRS what you took out of HSA, and you also certify how much of that money was spent on medical expenses.  If any of it was spent on something else, taxes and penalties are due.